# Change factor to numeric in dataframe and drop missing values

Tags: r

I have downloaded the data and would like to change columns named USD and EUR to numeric and also treat the column date as a date. I would also like to get rid of the missing values in the dataframe named result3.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) 

getNBPRates <- function(year) {
  url1 <- sprintf(
    paste0("https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/Archiwum/archiwum_tab_a_", year, ".csv"), 
    year)
  url1 <- read.csv2(url1, header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=",") %>% 
    select(data, X1USD, X1EUR) %>% 
    rename(usd=X1USD, eur=X1EUR, date=data) %>%
    slice(-1)
  transform(url1, date = as.Date(as.character(date), "%Y%m%d"))
}

a <- getNBPRates(year=2015)

head(as.data.frame(a))

years<- c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)

result <- lapply(years, getNBPRates)

result3 <- Reduce(rbind, result)
```

Comment: `Error: object 'getNBPRates' not found`. Also, `Reduce(rbind, result)` is horribly inefficient and will get very slow with more data; use instead `do.call(rbind, result)`. The difference is that with `Reduce`, rbind is copied `n-1` times (where `n` is `length(years)` here), and with each time it makes a complete copy of the data in memory ... eventually that gets big and slow; with `do.call`, rbind is called only once. No copying-over-copying-over-copying ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getNBPRates <- function(year) {
  url1 <- sprintf(paste0("https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/Archiwum/archiwum_tab_a_", year, ".csv"))
  url1 <- read.csv2(url1, header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=",", fileEncoding = "Windows-1250")
  url1 <- url1 |>
    select(data, X1USD, X1EUR) |>
    slice(-1) |>
    filter(row_number()<= n()-3) |>
    mutate(data = as.Date(data, format = "%Y%m%d"), usd = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", X1USD)), eur = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", X1EUR))) |>
    select(-c(X1USD, X1EUR))
}

years<- c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)
result <- lapply(years, getNBPRates)
result3 <- Reduce(rbind, result)
```

And what you understand with *"to get rid of the missing values in dataframe named result3."?* If that's the missing dates, then you have to substitute it with some logic. If I'm not mistaken - if there is no NBP for particular day, a last one has to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

To change a column to numeric you can use `as.numeric(column_name)`

Based on the date format in the archiwum_tab_a_2015.csv file, you can change the date column with `as.Date(column_name, format = "%Y%m%d")`

To remove all missing values you can use `complete.cases(data)`:

```
mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]
```

Comment: When I use as.numeric(column_name), almost the whole column is with missing values. Also the complete.cases(data) creates the values True or false and don't remove missing values

Comment: You just need to index the whole dataframe using the results of `complete.cases`, so something like `mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]`.  As for using `as.numeric` if you have missing values there isn't much you can do. I would suggest removing the missing values first, although you might find the data needs further pre-processing if values which *should* convert to numeric are becoming NA after using `as.numeric`